# flutter doctor git issue on macOS sierra

Tags: git, macos, flutter

I download flutter dev 0.5.7 on macOS high Sierra
and update my path and now can't run flutter doctor I am getting Error:

> The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
>   The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
>   to set up Flutter, run the following command:
>   git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Comment: Did you install git? try running git in terminal

Comment: If not, install it from here: https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Since dev 0.5.3 its working... suddenly upgraded to 0.5.8 and didn't compile my app due to some plugin error because of 0.5.8. I delete everything in fluter folder and download 0.5.7 and got the above error. Its not a git issue. I have git 2.15 install and the test the all path that its working...

Comment: The logs say flutter directory doesn't contain .git directory. did you remove everything inside flutter folder or the folder itself?

Comment: yes I remove everything, after your response I clean everything related to Flutter and mange to re-install again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's either missing git tool which you can download [from here](https://git-scm.com/). Or the flutter directory doesn't contain ".git" folder. This folder is hidden and you may not see it.

To fix this issue, you should remove flutter completely and install it again.

Note: Problem is solved in comments. Updating post for other users.